# Call method from current Java context

Tags: nativescript

Currently I'm sending a text message from Android using the `SmsManager` and its working fine.

But I do want to listen to the Intent result and take some actions based on that, the following code was supposed to work, but I'm getting `getResultCode` as undefined on the runtime (But it works on the debugging console)

```
app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(this.id, () => {
        if(this.getResultCode() == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK){
            // Sucess
        } else {
            // Failure
        }
    });
```

How do I get the value from the `getResultCode` method properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the arrow function, thus getting the wrong context.

Changing from arrow function to a standard function fixed the problem

```
app.android.registerBroadcastReceiver(this.id, function(){
        if(this.getResultCode() == android.app.Activity.RESULT_OK){
            // Sucess
        } else {
            // Failure
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `application` module which exposes the android context.

[https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/*application*.androidapplication#context](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_application_.androidapplication#context)

EDIT

```
import * as app from 'tns-core-modules/application';

// then below is the Android context object
app.android.context;
```

Comment: Can you please expand how to do that ? Right now I fixed the problem by moving from arrow function to a standard function. This way I can access the correct context from JS.

Comment: I wouldn't guess that would fix your problem. I believe you were wanting the Android Context, which is what the `application` module exposes a reference to. You're still using `this` in javascript. Unless you're using the Static Binding Generator to `extend` a native class here.

Comment: Now that I looked over what you're doing, I was wrong. what you're doing makes more sense now.